# Accessing URL to use issues (expo/react native app/firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

In my current app i want the user to pick a photo from their phone and then to use the downloadable url from firebase storage to then add it to my database.  Everything works but when a user(when they first time to pick a image) it says

> TypeError:  Network request failed

**code(logic/state/functions):**

```
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);  
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)
  async function postImage () {
    try {
      // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
         let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
           mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
           allowsEditing: true,
           aspect: [4, 3],
           quality: 1,
         });
     
     
         if (!result.canceled) {
          imgFirebase()
          setImage(result.assets[0].uri);         }

         }
         catch(E) {
          Alert.alert(
            "Alert Title",
            "My Alert Msg 1",
            [
              {
                text: "Cancel",
                onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
                style: "cancel"
              },
              { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
            ]
          );
         }
  }

  async function imgFirebase () {
    try {
      console.log(image);
     const d = await fetch(image)
    const dd = await d.blob()
    const fileName = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
    const storage = getStorage();
   const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
   uploadBytes(storageRef,dd).then((snapshot) => {
     getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(async (url) => {
 
       // Create a query against the collection.
       setUrl(url)
       console.log(url)
 }).catch(e=>{
  Alert.alert(
    "Alert Title",
    "My Alert Msg 2",
    [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
        style: "cancel"
      },
      { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
    ]
  );
 }) 
   }); 
    }
    catch(e) {
     alert(e)
    }
   }
```

**code(for rendered UI):**

```
 <Pressable color="#000" style={{marginTop:20,backgroundColor:"#FF35F0",padding:10,borderRadius:11,color:"#000"}} onPress={postImage}>
      <Text style={{color:"#fff",textAlign:"center",fontSize:20}}>Pick Image</Text>
    </Pressable>
```

whats also weird is that after the first time getting this error and then trying to pick a image the error finally goes away.  Why does this error come up at first?  How would i fix this?